# View em SQL ERROR

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando montar um `SQL` para usar na metodologia `view`. Mas ao executar, produz um erro.

Eu preciso como resultado a quantidade de itens que estão na condição 'Liberado' e a quantidade de itens que estão na condição 'Em Uso'. Então, tentei fazer dessa forma abaixo, mas apresentou erro.

Há alguma outra maneira de fazer com que eu consiga trazer estes resultados?

**SQL - CODE**

```
SELECT
    c1.id_ativo_externo,
    c1.id_obra,
    c2.codigo_obra,
    c2.endereco,
    c2.endereco_cidade,
    c1.condicao,
    c1.situacao,
    IF c1.condicao = 'Liberado' THEN count(*) as total_liberado ELSE count(*) as total_emuso END IF
FROM ativo_externo AS c1
JOIN obra AS c2 ON c2.id_obra=c1.id_obra
```

**ERROR - CODE**

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'c1.condicao = 'Liberado' THEN count(*) as total_liberado ELSE count(*) as tot...' at line 9
```

Pesquisei sobre as terminologias `IF THEN ELSE`, mas não obtive êxito.

**Modificação:** Removido o `WHERE`.

Comment: Se você possui o filtro `WHERE c1.condicao = 'Liberado'`, por que precisa da condição `IF c1.condicao = 'Liberado'` visto que sempre será TRUE?

Comment: A sua SQL está errado no modo geral, principalmente no `WHERE` já nem precisa usar esse if que inclusive faz a mesma coisa só muda em termos a etiqueta, apesar que o if ta errado. Ou seja, ta tudo errado.

Comment: Na verdade, a query que eu preciso montar é retornar todos os que estão liberados e todos os que estão em uso... Por isso tinha o Where Liberado, mas teriamos que tirar isso.

Answer (score 0):

> Há alguma outra maneira de fazer com que eu consiga trazer estes
> resultados?

Sim, uma outra forma de trazer esse resultado seria com a utilização de subconsultas conforme exemplo a seguir:

```
SELECT
    c1.id_ativo_externo,
    c1.id_obra,
    c2.codigo_obra,
    c2.endereco,
    c2.endereco_cidade,
    c1.condicao,
    c1.situacao,
    (Select count(*) 
       from ativo_externo a 
       where a.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo 
       and c1.condicao = 'Liberado')  as total_liberado,
    (Select count(*) 
       from ativo_externo a 
       where a.id_ativo_externo = c1.id_ativo_externo 
       and c1.condicao = 'Em uso')  as total_emuso        
FROM ativo_externo AS c1
JOIN obra AS c2 ON c2.codigo_obra=c1.id_obra
```

Foi necessário realizar uma correção na consulta original, pois na linha `JOIN obra AS c2 ON c2.id_obra=c1.id_obra` menciona `c2.id_obra` mas nos campos da consulta temos `Select ... c2.codigo_obra`, por isso é necessário corrigir para `JOIN obra AS c2 ON c2.codigo_obra=c1.id_obra`, por exemplo.

Na consulta sugerida, está sendo realizada uma subconsulta para gerar o resultado `total_liberado` e outra subconsulta para gerar o resultado `total_liberado`.